# Saving the JavaRDD in Elastic Search using ES Hadoop connector

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

Currently working on a transformation project where I need to feed the data to elastic search from Oracle. So my work goes like this

```
1. Sqoop - From oracle
2. Java Spark - Dataframe Joins then saving them into elastic search repo's
```

And my elastic document will look like

```
{
Field 1: Value
Field 2: value
Field 3: Value
Field 4: [               -- Array of Maps
   {
    Name: Value
    Age: Value
   },{
    Name: Value
    Age: Value
   }
]
Field 5:{                -- Maps
   Code :Value
   Key : Value
}
}
```

So would like to know, how to form a javaRDD for the above structure.

I have coded till dataframe join and got stuck, Unable to proceed from there.
So I want my data in normalized  form

My spark code

```
Dataframe esDF = df.select(
df.col("Field1") , df.col("Field2") ,df.col("Field3") 
 ,df.col("Name") ,df.col("Age") ,
  df.col("Code"),df.col("Key")
)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

1 - Use saveToES method in dataFrame itself. ( this may not be supported in older versions , works for elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.1.jar

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

dataFrame.saveToEs("<index>/<type>",Map(("es.nodes" -> <ip:port>"))
```

2 - Create a case class and use RDD[] method to save. ( Works for older versions as well )

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
case class ESDoc(...)
val rdd = df.map( row => EsDoc(..))
rdd.saveToEs("<index>/<type>",Map(("es.nodes" -> <ip:port>"))
```

3 - With older versions of scala ( [< 2.11](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296?_ga=2.137920503.673009265.1494547252-845129159.1494547252) )  , you will be stuck with 22 fields limit in case class . Note that you can use Map instead of case class

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
val rdd  = df.map( row => Map(<key>:<value>...) )
rdd.saveToEs("<index>/<type>",Map(("es.nodes" -> <ip:port>")) // saves RDD[Map<K,V>]
```

For all above methods, you may want to pass es.batch.write.retry.count to appropriate value , or -1 ( infinite retries) if you have another way of controlling lifecycle of EMR ( making sure it wont run for ever)

```
   val esOptions = Map("es.nodes" -> <host>:<port>, "es.batch.write.retry.count" -> "-1")
```

Comment: I doubt whether the below approach would form the structure that ES want, 
JavaRDD<class> esRDD = df.javaRDD.map(y -> class.builder()
.field1(y.getString(0))
.field2(y.getString(1))
.field3(y.getString(2))
.field4(ImmutableList.of
(ImmutableMap.of
("Name",y.getString(3),"Age",y.getString(4)) ))
field5(ImmutableMap.of("Code",y.getString(5),"Key", y.getString(6)))
 ).build()
JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(esRDD , "index/type");
This will create one es doc with only one ArrayList for field4, for the next list it will create the second document. But my case single dcument should have list of maps